# How to create models to handle multiple tables in zend framework 2.0

Tags: zend-framework2

I am new to zend framework, and have straight away started with zf2.

I am trying to build models which can handle multiple tables. I am using the following as references

Zend Framework: Documentation: Create a Model and Database Table - Zend Framework Manual

and

Getting started with Zend Framework 2 (beta) – Rob Allen's DevNotes

Now, I was successful in building a model with table gateway pattern as given in Akrabat's zf2 application.

But table gateway pattern would only support a single table.

So I tired to experiment with zend Dbtable so as to use zend_db_tables' relationship feature.

In above link (quick start for models) Dbtable extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract. Incase of zf 2.0 how can I achieve this?

In the library folder I see zend/Db/table doesn't exist in zf 2.0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might not be what you're looking for, but the TableGateway doesn't have to be your sole Model. You can have a Model like "IceManager" and in that model you bring two gateways together, like `$im->setIceModel($iceGateway)` and `$im->setWaffleModel($waffleGateway)` and then work with the two approriately

Comment: Thanks Sam, I could keep this as a option. But certainly there should be a way ZF2 models can handle joins. Anybody who has started of with zf2 and has a insight into this, it would be helpful if they could share some knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Updates to Zend\Db are happening to support joins in a select when Beta 4 is released. The code to be incorporated is currently here: https://github.com/ralphschindler/zf2/blob/feature/db-story-next/library/Zend/Db/Sql/Select.php#L196